# User name not hyperlinked in a comment although the user exists

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, username

In [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1055791/458893), I can find [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1055791/please-suggest-some-safety-measures-for-analysing-viruses-on-my-pendrive/1055793#comment1481293_1055793) in which the username `user105127` is not hyperlinked to the [user profile](https://superuser.com/users/574391/user105127).

I think that this is a bug.

Comment: If you look at `http://superuser.com/users/574391/user105127?tab=activity&sort=comments` that comment does not appear ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timeline would be:

1. The question was asked on Security Stack Exchange, where the asker had an account and where they left comments
2. The question was then migrated to Super User, where the asker did not have an account
3. The asker created an account after the migration, but the comments remain as they are, "unlinked" to their account

That's how it is.

There is an [open feature-request to have that fixed up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110765/when-a-question-is-migrated-re-associate-the-comments-when-the-user-creates-an), where the comment author is linked back up to the owner.

But, like most comments, it's not really important to anything and could do well enough to just be deleted.

Comment: Comments are not designed to be around forever.  We have unique problems, so sometimes we have to pull teeth...I mean information from people, but once we get that information those comments should  be deleted once its part of the question.  In other words like random I don't see this bug being fixed anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, see [Comment authors are not getting migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121052/comment-authors-are-not-getting-migrated) with status-deferred tag. The report is over four years old, and it had the "deferred" tag since 2014, so this is probably not getting fixed soon.